# Python Def function Outcome, call a Class function in Python

Tags: python

### What does the function spades_high do?

I don't understand the concept of this function and I want to know what it does
what does the spades_high function doing in code given below?and what is the purpose of spade_high function.(sorry for my bad english). Thanks a lot

```
import collections


Card = collections.namedtuple('Card',['rank','suit'])


class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2,11)] + list("JDKA")
    suits = 'spades diamond clubs heart'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(rank,suit) for suit in self.suits
                      for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def __getitem__(self,positions):
        return self.cards[positions]

suit_values = dict(spades = 3,heart = 2,diamond = 1, clubs = 0)

def spades_high(card):
    rank_value = FrenchDeck.ranks.index(card.rank)
    return rank_value * len(suit_values) + suit_values[card.suit]
```

Comment: I just answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

### In few words, in summing the score of a choosen card

```
import collections


Card = collections.namedtuple('Card',['rank','suit'])


class FrenchDeck(): # added brackets
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2,11)] + list("JDKA")
    suits = 'spades diamond clubs heart'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [Card(rank,suit) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cards)

    def __getitem__(self,positions):
        return self.cards[positions]

suit_values = dict(spades = 3,heart = 2,diamond = 1, clubs = 0)

def spades_high(card):
    '''
    The variable rank_value is calling the variable "ranks" inside the FrenchDeck class,
    which is getting the index within the list of the card's rank
    '''
    rank_value = FrenchDeck.ranks.index(card.rank) 
    return rank_value * len(suit_values) + suit_values[card.suit]


y = FrenchDeck()
for card in sorted(y,key=spades_high): print(card)
```

this will give cards in increasing order(with ace being highest; then by suit in order: spade(highest), heart, diamond and clubs

Comment: but i am using spades_high function as key in sorted function. which give output of card in increasing order(with aces being
highest), then by suit in the order: spades (highest), then hearts, diamonds and clubs
(lowest)

Comment: You mean for card in sorted(y,key=spades_high): print(card)? If not then I dont understand what you want to know

Comment: i dont understand how card are sorted in increasing order by using spades_high function as a key in sorted. Can you explain me how cards are sorted in increasing order(with ace being highest, then by suit in the order: spades(highest),then heart, daimond and clubs(lowest).